# Changing navigationController title after viewdidload

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When I set `self.navigationItem.title` in `viewdidload` the title appears correctly, Later based on user interaction I am updating the title. The length of title is fixated to length of the title that is set in `viewdidload`.

This is want happening in my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                                                  [UIColor brownColor]: NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                                  [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:12.0]: NSFontAttributeName}];
     self.navigationItem.title = @"My Account";
}


- (void)updateTitleWithUserName {
     self.navigationItem.title = @"Test User 167";
}
```

**Result:**

Test...

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: self.title = @"Your_Title" is enough to set the navigation title.

Comment: @Suhail: no this one not a good idea if you have tabbar then it'l create some problem like title replaced in both the places(tabar index title and navigation bar title.)

Comment: when u calling updateTitle method?

Comment: When user taps on a button.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a label for title so you can adjust its size to fit like this on viewDidLoad, then just change tlabel on update and assign it to the nav title. (Manage color and fonts as you wish)

```
    self.title = @"Your TiTle Text";
    UILabel* tlabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 40)];
    tlabel.text=self.navigationItem.title;
    tlabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    tlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size: 30.0];
    tlabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    self.navigationItem.titleView=tlabel;
```

Comment: If the text is too long the title creeps under the back button.

Comment: Well, its suposed to be a title not a full text

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    titleLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 40)];// create instance variable UILabel * titleLabel;
    titleLabel.text=@"My Account";
    titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size: 16.0];
    titleLabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    self.navigationItem.titleView= titleLabel;
}
- (void)updateTitleWithUserName 
{
     titleLabel.text = @"Test User 167";
}
```

Comment: If the text is too long the title creeps under the back button.